# Sort an array of objects containing a date array

Tags: javascript, momentjs, dayjs

I am currently attempting to sort an array of objects, and each object contains an array of dates. The data structure looks like the following:

```
const array = [
  {
    name: "Judith",
    cal: {
      ti: [
        "2021-03-09T15:00:00Z",
        "2021-03-09T15:30:00Z",
        "2021-03-16T14:00:00Z"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    name: "billy",
    cal: {
      ti: [
        "2021-03-05T14:30:00Z",
        "2021-03-08T14:00:00Z",
        "2021-03-08T14:30:00Z"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I am attempting to sort the array based on the closest available time to now using the date library known as `dayjs`.  I am attempting to compare each array of dates using the diff method within the dayjs package like so:

```
const test = array.map(i => i.cal.ti.sort((a, b) => {
 dayjs(a).diff(dayjs(b))
}))

console.log(test)
```

I would like to sort the objects contained within the array returning the object with the closest available time first and so on and so forth.  I am noticing I am returning incorrectly within the sort and I believe I have a whole mess of issues going on as well, where I am not comparing the dates correctly causing my sort of the array to fail.

Attached is a repl.it for debugging:

https://repl.it/@rterrell25/LegalJaggedCoordinate#index.js

Comment: If the format of the strings in the time array will be consistent, wouldn't the default array sort method (alphabetical ascending) do the trick without the extra overhead of dayjs?

Comment: would the sort method, sort the dates correctly without having to convert them?

Comment: It should in this case. I'll put an example in a proper answer below.

Comment: much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```js
const array = [
  {
    name: "Judith",
    cal: {
      ti: [
        "2021-03-16T14:00:00Z",
        "2021-03-09T15:00:00Z",
        "2021-03-09T15:30:00Z",
        "2021-03-19T15:30:00Z",
        "2021-02-19T15:30:00Z",
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    name: "billy",
    cal: {
      ti: [
        "2021-03-08T14:00:00Z",
        "2021-03-05T14:30:00Z",
        "2021-02-25T14:30:00Z",
        "2021-03-25T14:30:00Z",
        "2021-03-08T14:30:00Z"
      ]
    }
  }
];

const now = new Date();

array.forEach(i => i.cal.ti.sort((a, b) =>
    Math.abs(new Date(a) - now)
    - Math.abs(new Date(b) - now)
));

array.sort((a, b) =>
    Math.abs(new Date(a.cal.ti[0]) - now)
    - Math.abs(new Date(b.cal.ti[0]) - now)
);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: this is what I am attempting to implement, the issue is however I'm noticing billy has the closest available date yet judith is returned first

Comment: "2021-03-16T14:00:00Z" is not the closest of all?

Comment: is not 3-5-1430 the closest?

Comment: curious if 3-5-1430 is the next available time

Comment: sorry, seems I missed the "time to now" part, see updated answer, I added some additional values to make the result more explicit

Answer (score 1):

In your test data, the dates are *already* sorted, so that might skew your perception of what's going on already.

I re-ordered the test data so that they start un-sorted and then changed your sort very slightly so that it returns either -1 or 1 (which is what sort functions should be returning):

```
const array = [
  {
    name: "Judith",
    cal: {
      ti: [
        "2021-03-16T14:00:00Z",
        "2021-03-09T15:00:00Z",
        "2021-03-09T15:30:00Z",
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    name: "billy",
    cal: {
      ti: [
        "2021-03-08T14:00:00Z",
        "2021-03-05T14:30:00Z",
        "2021-03-08T14:30:00Z"
      ]
    }
  }
]
const test = array.map(i => i.cal.ti.sort((a, b) => (dayjs(a).isAfter(dayjs(b)) ? 1 : -1)))
 
 console.log(test)
```

**Update**:

```
const test = array.sort((a,b) => {
  let aFirst = a.cal.ti.map(i => dayjs(i)).sort((a1,b1) => a1.isAfter(b1) ? 1 : -1)[0]
  let bFirst = b.cal.ti.map(i => dayjs(i)).sort((a1,b1) => a1.isAfter(b1) ? 1 : -1)[0]
  return aFirst.isAfter(bFirst) ? 1 : -1
})
 console.log(test)
```

This method of sorting `dayjs` objects comes from a suggestion here (https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/328)

Regarding your note about returning -- if you use `{}` to wrap your function body, you should be using the `return` inside the braces. You'll note that in my sort function, there aren't any braces -- in this case the return value from the one-line function is taken automatically.

Comment: in the solution you provided, I'm noticing that billy's dates are still returned second as opposed to Judith who has the next closest available time.

Comment: I don't want to sort the actual dates within the ti array I want to sort the objects contained within the overarching array by who has the next closest available time

Comment: Ah -- that was clear in my reading of the question. Please see the update. Keep in mind that a commenter was correct, it isn't totally necessary with your current data format to use dayjs (you could just do string comparison), but if you had dates formatted differently, it would be useful.